# Multi result Json to DataTable data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable

I try pass result: Array from json:
`{success: true, result: Array(9), error: null}`

To DataTable:

```
myTable.DataTable({
            ajax: {
                dataType: 'json',
                url: GetJason,
                error: function (x, y) {
                    console.log(x.error);
                }
            },
            columns: [......
```

How to force use result array by Datatable.
Any ideas, many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more detail here? Like what's the expected data format in "columns" and the format of data in "result"?

Comment: Hey this is array of objects, with many different variables. Let's say it will be one column with string.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to just pass the "result" array to "columns"? or reformat result in a specific way before passing it to the column?

Comment: I just want to pass "result" array to "columns"...

Comment: the json format is wrong for datatables.  use data instead of result.  [link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)